# How to Read/Modify line with specific position after specified string with repeatable paragraphs? Also print all lines

Tags: python, string, str-replace, enumeration

I need to Modify few lines after a specific string(probably paragraph title) like prefix adding tab space etc to the line based on line index position.

```
text = """Para 1
example line one
example blah blah line 
example line one
example blah blah line 
Some other lines 1
some other lines 2
Para 2
another para line start
another para line start goes
another para line three
another para line four
Para 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4"""
for x in text:
    if x == 'Para':
        print('Starting specified loop')
        for x in text:
            if x % 2 == 0: #line 2,4 after string to modify
                print('In specified loop   ', x)
            else:
                print("Out Specified loop",x)    
    else:
        print('all other lines', x)
```

This code found in stack and works fine for xrange numbers but for text it gives error.Also i have tried with enumerator but that prints all the line irrespective of line position.  The output which i expect modifying line 2 and 4 after string Para:

```
Para 1
example line one
     example blah blah line 
example line one
     example blah blah line 
Some other lines 1
some other lines 2
Para 2
another para line start
    another para line start goes
another para line three
    another para line four
Para 3
line 1
    line 2
line 3
    line 4
```

Hope i have explained in brief. Thanks for your time and Patience and awaiting Response please.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = """
Para 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
Some other lines 1
some other lines 2
Para 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
Para 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
"""

res = text.split("\n")
# print(res)

for each_word in res:
    if "line 2" in each_word or "line 4" in each_word:
        print "    ",each_word
    else:
        print each_word
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually Line 1 2 3 4 are examples. The line content anything .I need to select the position after Para Line 2 and 4. NOT "line 2" or "line 4". Line index position 2 and 4 or anything after that string.```lines to read in position 0,1,2,3,4etc ```. Actually This will NOT WORK as per the requirement. Thanks again for response. Hope you will update the code.